# Probability that Brownian motion hits both hemispheres

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

The problem is to find:

$P_{x}(\{T_{B_{1}}<\infty\}\cap \{T_{B_{2}}<\infty\})$ where $B_{1},B_{2}$ are the two hemispheres of sphere S shown below. There are two possible paths for first hitting time: a)paths that enter S through one cap and exit via the opposite one b)paths that hit both caps for the first time without crossing the blue disk.

[image]

**For a)**

One idea is to first use the hitting probability for sphere S and then Poissons formula for the probability that BM will escape the S from ,say, the $B_{1}$ cap.

For $x\in B_{2}$, Poissons formula is $P_{x}(T_{S}=T_{B_{1}})=C\int_{B_{1}}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}dS_{y}$. So as we see it depends on the entry point of BM into $B_{2}$. Thus, we don't have independence.

But we do have a lower bound, by taking the furthest point x from $B_{1}$ i.e. the pole of $B_{2}$ call it $x_{0}$

So we get the lower bound $P_{x_{0}}(T_{B_{1}}=T_{S})P_{x}(T_{S}<\infty)=C\frac{R^{n-2}}{|x|^{n-2}}\int_{B_{1}}\frac{1}{|x_{0}-y|^{n-2}}dS_{y}$.

**For b)**

I am not sure

Thanks